# What is causing iPhone Simulator rendering a site different than a physical device?

Tags: html, ios, css

My problem is that I have elements in different positions depending on what device is viewing them. Here I have a screen shot from an iPhone 5s: [image]

And then here is a screenshot from the iPhone 5s Simulator in Xcode:

[image]

I'm trying to achieve this layout without any large spaces between content across all devices. Previously, the same problem occurred on iPads. Take a look at my source here: http://eugeneross.com/cw-2

Comment: from what this noob understands, simulators are just that. simulators. they don't run on the same engine as the device they are simulating so they will often give bad results. having said that, chrome developer tools seems to be the best simulator i have found. click on the phone icon in the upper left hand corner.

Comment: I've used developer tools to check if the layout is correct. It appears correct in developer tools but is still wrong on a physical device.